# Does unattended-upgrades also include apt-get autoremove?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, cron, unattended-upgrades

Say I recently installed unattended-upgrades via:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades -y
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades -y
```

Does unattended-upgrades also include `apt-get autoremove`?

Or should I add a weekly cronjob atop the unattended-upgrades layer to make sure dependencies of deleted packages are removed as well, via `crontab -e` and then:

```
0 0 * * 0 apt-get autoremove -y
```

---

<sub>Note: Feel free to mention similar apt concepts besides autoremove if these are needed.</sub>

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Whether or not `unattended-upgrades` will perform the cleanup (auto remove) is controlled by the `Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies` setting in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. Set it as follows to enable the cleanup -- and you should be able to remove the explicit autoremove cron-job:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies  "true";
```

Comment: Before enabling this, consider whether or not it's necessary - newer versions of `unattended-upgrades` have the option `Remove-New-Unused-Dependencies` enabled automatically, which basically performs `autoremove`, but only for packages newly made unused after an upgrade run. (The `Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages` option mentioned below also appears to be enabled by default now.)

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Mikhail's suggestion, it is also useful to autoremove unused kernel packages. This will keep the `/boot/` partition from filling up on some Ubuntu systems. A full /boot partition can lead to issues.

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";
```

Comment: This might qualify as a comment, but not as an answer in any case.